# Cannot get loop to run

Tags: loops, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am trying to get my frequency table to fully display but while trying to run the loop
through the next label it gives me an exception handler error. I am wondering how I can get my loop to run fully

My code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

target BYTE "AAEBDCFBBC", 0
freqTable DWORD 256 DUP(0)
introPrompt BYTE "Here are the indexes in hex and their counts in the array: ", 0ah,     
0dh, 0
prompt BYTE "Location ", 0
prompt2 BYTE " : ", 0
numcount DWORD 0
sLength DWORD ?
location DWORD ?
count DWORD 0
temp BYTE ?

.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET target
call StrLength
mov sLength, eax

Get_frequencies PROTO, 
    pval1: DWORD,
    tableVal: DWORD
INVOKE Get_frequencies, ADDR target, ADDR freqTable

mov eax, numCount
call WriteDec
call crlf

mov edx, OFFSET introPrompt
call WriteString

;Writes the frequency table
mov esi, OFFSET freqTable
mov ecx, 256
top:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString

    mov eax, count
    call WriteHex

    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call WriteString

    mov eax, [esi]
    call WriteDec

    call crlf
    add esi, 4
    inc count
    loop top

call WaitMsg
exit
main ENDP

Get_frequencies PROC USES edi esi,
pval1: DWORD,
tableVal: DWORD

mov edi, pval1      ;edi points to target array
mov esi, pval1      ;esi points to freqTable

mov edx, 0
mov eax, 0
mov numCount, 0
L1:
    mov al, [edi]
    mov dl, [esi]

    mov temp, dl
    cmp al, 0
    jne L2
    jmp next

L2:
    inc edi
    cmp al, dl
    jne L1
    inc numCount
    jmp L1

next:

    mov ecx, esi
    mov ecx, tableVal
    imul edx, 4
    add ecx, edx
    mov ebx, numCount
    mov [ecx], ebx

    cmp temp, 0
    je finish

    inc esi
    inc edi
    jmp L1

finish:
ret
Get_frequencies ENDP

END main
```

So the numCount global variable contains how many times a character is repeated and I add the number to the frequency table depending on the hex value. I try to increase the esi and edi to go again starting at the following value on the start but it gives me an exception handle error.

Thank you very much

Comment: Where exactly in the code do you get an exception? What type of exception is it? Are you sure WriteString, WriteHex, WriteDec subroutines preserve ECX value?

Comment: @Ruud: `pval1` and `tableVal` contains addresses to arrays. These addresses are bound to the arguments on this line: `INVOKE Get_frequencies, ADDR target, ADDR freqTable`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too familiar with MASM; thanks for the explanation. Next question: `mov esi, pval1 ;esi points to freqTable`, shouldn't that be `mov esi,tableVal`? Looks like a copy/paste mistake from the line immediately above.

Comment: In `Get_frequencies`, you should put `mov edx, 0` _underneath_ label `L1`. This statement _must_ be executed repeatedly, otherwise your repeated multiplication `imul edx, 4` will spill non-zero values into `dh`. This _must_ be cleared, otherwise `edx` will quickly grow out of bounds and overrun the frequency table.

Comment: Thank you very much Ruud, you pointed me to the right direction. It turned out not only did I not reset edx to 0 before every loop, but I also did not reset numCount. Again, thank you very much.